# How to add additional product on order summary when customer click on specific shipping method

Tags: magento2, shipping, onestepcheckout

I want to add additional product on the checkout page with the already added product through add to cart in the order summary.

how can I achieve that is there anyone have an idea??

Comment: after add shipping method automatically add product in to cart ???

Comment: once the customer clicks on free shipping I want to add one product by default free with the already added product through add to car o order summary